# how to make pictures go alone placing

Tags: javascript, html, image

How to make this img go alone placing? all images have width=300, 3 images/row, but the height are random, then.. how to make the 2 and after rows put just in the bottom of the before row?

```
    <section id="contenedor">
    <div id="imagen"><img src="x" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="x" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="x" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="x" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="x" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="x" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="x" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="x" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="x" class="ancho" />300</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? I don't understand.

Comment: id can be only one on  a page, so please replace <div id="imagen"> with <div class="imagen">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. But I have a feeling you will want to investigate the jQuery Masonry plugin:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

It allows you to lay out images (and other elements) in a fluid layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add the style:

```
<style>
#imagen{
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
}
#imagen img{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.split{
    clear: left;
}
</style>
```

and add the `<div class="split"></div>` every 3 images. just like:

```
<section id="contenedor">
    <div id="imagen"><img src="200.jpg" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="300.jpg" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="400.jpg" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div class="split"></div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="300.jpg" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="400.jpg" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="200.jpg" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div class="split"></div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="400.jpg" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="300.jpg" class="ancho" />300</div>
    <div id="imagen"><img src="300.jpg" class="ancho" />300</div>
</section>
```